# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have to assess the convergence of  $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

I'm told that it diverges, but can't really see why.

The divergence test doesn't really help, because 
$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$, so

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=0$, which doesn't conclude its divergence.

I doubt the ratio test would be much of use in this situation.

I can't imagine using the integral comparison test, as I wouldn't know where to start with $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limit-compare to $\sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  You need the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin(1/\sqrt{n})}{1/\sqrt{n}}
$$
which is $1$ by a change of variables, making use of
$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\sin t}{t}=1.
$$
To get from point A to point B, change variables by $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  As $n \to \infty$, $t \to 0^+$.

Since $\sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, so does your series.

The terms in your series are positive, so this is legal.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I would, to improve the clarity of your answer for future readers, elaborate on the change of variables explanation, i.e. how you got from $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \displaystyle \frac{\sin(1/\sqrt{n})}{1/\sqrt{n}}$ to $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \displaystyle \frac{\sin t}{t}=1.$

Answer (score 4):

Use the inequality that $\sin x\geq\dfrac{2}{\pi}x$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Could you explain how you arrive at the comparison please?

Comment: The inequality comes from the convexity of $\sin$ on $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the derivative of the function $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ on $(0,\pi/2]$ and try to argue that it is decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a limit comparison with $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, since

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sin(x) \geq\dfrac{2}{\pi}x$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$

$\sum_{n} 1/n^{1/2}$ diverge

$\forall n: \sin(1/n^{1/2}) \geq \dfrac{2}{\pi n^{1/2}}$